# Is there any option to edit the flags?

Tags: support, flags

I have flagged a question recently for the reason that the question is too broad to answer. Later,I found that the question is corrected by the user.Now, I need to remove my flag. How can I remove my flag from that question?

Comment: You can't retract a flag. Just move on. It will probably be declined.

Comment: If my flag is declined, then I am warned for flagging unwanted posts. Is this a real red mark on me for flagging such questions?

Comment: @Ganesh No, it is not a big problem if you occasionally have a declined flag. I have some myself and I'm still here. Don't worry too much about that. Just take note of the message the mod leaves on your flag.

Comment: you can retract close votes when you get to the required rep to cast them directly

Answer (score 4):

Don't worry.

If the flag is declined then as long as it's the exception then it won't affect your ability to flag in the future.

What's more likely to happen is that another user will see the flag and mark it as invalid, which will have the effect of marking your flag as "disputed". Disputed flags don't affect your future ability to flag.